# Get min and max values for getOrientation on accelerometer?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am currently working with the accelerometer on Android, and have run into an interesting situation. I need to find out the maximum values for the following, WITHOUT requiring the end user to flop their phone around in some elaborate calibration routine. The values I am looking for specifically are...

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    SensorManager.getOrientation(outR, xyz);

    float X, Y, XMax, YMax;

    X = xyz[1];
    Y = xyz[2];

    XMax = ???;
    YMax = ???;
}
```

I've poked around online, but have not had much luck determining what the values would be (it appears it changes from phone to phone), nor seen anyone mention a way to pull that value from somewhere.

Does anyone know how I might determine the maximum/minimum values of xyz[1] and xyz[2]?

UPDATE: An Example of what I mean is the following:

When I report directly the outputed float from xyz[1], and then move my phone forward and backward all the way, I get the following results:

min value it reports: -1.50 (give or take a 10ths)
max value it reports: 1.50 (give or take a 10ths)

when I roll my phone left and right, I get the following for xyz[2]:

min value it reports: -3.14 (give or take a 10ths)
max value it reports: 3.14 (give or take a 10ths)

I was told this changes between phones, however this could be wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what max/min values you're talking about but getOrientation will populate a vector with the following data:

```
xyz[0]: azimuth [-π,π]
xyz[1]: pitch [-π,π]
xyz[2]: roll [-π/2,π/2]
```

From [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation(float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D)):

> All three angles above are in radians and positive in the
> counter-clockwise direction.

Refer also to the SensorManager.java:1094 class:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b267554/core/java/android/hardware/SensorManager.java

Comment: I updated my question to explain what I meant on min and max values, and what I'm seeing on my end! The pitch values you listed look like they correspond to what I'm seeing, but the roll values Im actually getting [-π, π]. Does that sound correct?